# Hide Django logo/name in header Django admin tool

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I want to hide/change the name displayed in the header bar, the label that I want to change is "DJANGO" word as the next image shows"

[image: Header with the DJANGO at the left]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution for customizing the admin header.

Just copy `/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html` from django source ([Link Here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html)) and paste it under your templates directory.

For example,

```
your_project/templates/admin/base_site.html
```

Now you can change whatever you like in this template.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to simply add the following lines to your main `urls.py`:

```
admin.site.site_title = 'My Heading'
admin.site.site_header = 'My Heading'
admin.site.index_title = 'My Heading'
```

See the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-attributes) for more attributes.

Comment: it didn't work, I Don't se any attribute to change the DJANGO link

Answer (score 1):

make a custom template file like:

templates/admin/base_site.html

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}YOUR WEB TITLE{%  endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">Your Site Name</h1>
{% endblock %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <style type="text/css">
        #header #branding h1{
                background: None;  // here you remove the django image

        }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Share improve with favicon icon :

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
**{% load staticfiles %}**
{% block title %}BROKR System{%  endblock %}
{% block extrahead %}

    **<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'img/logo1.png' %}"/>**
    {% endblock %}
{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">BROKR System</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to locate your

```
django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html
```

This might be located in your

```
env/lib/site-packages
```

Thus, you find it in

```
env/lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html
```

This is if you have virtual environment setup.

Else it will be in your base project folder containing your settings.py, wsgi.py etc

In:

```
your_base_folder/lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html
```

Then go to line 32-34

```
<div id="branding">{% block branding %}{% endblock %}</div>
```

Replace the below with your img or text or h1

```
{% block branding %}{% endblock %}
```

For example:

```
<div id="branding"><img href='example.png'></div>
```

Or You could use the preferred django's

```
{{% url (bla.bla bla) %}}
```